# Laravel 5.6.17 - Relationship query with condition

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `Laravel Framework 5.6.17`. I have 2 models that are linked via a [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) with a pivot table.

The models in question are `Question` and `Tag` linked with a `tag_question` table.

A Question can have many tags and a Tag can belong to many questions.

The models look like so:

```
class Question extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'title', 'body',
    ];

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function tags()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class, 'tag_question');
    }
}

class CreateQuestionsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('questions', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('questions');
    }
}
```

---

```
class Tag extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'tag',
    ];

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    public $timestamps = true;

    /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function questions()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Question::class, 'tag_question');
    }
}

class CreateTagsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tags', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('tag');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tags');
    }
}
```

The pivot looks like so:

```
class CreateTagQuestionTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('tag_question', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('question_id');
            $table->integer('tag_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('tag_question');
    }
}
```

Nothing out of the ordinary, fairly straight forward stuff.

**The problem**

I'm trying to filter Questions by Tags and I'm doing this with the following query:

```
$q = $question
    ->with(['tags' => function($query) use($request) {
        $query->where('tags.tag', '=',  $request->query('tag'));
    }])
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

However, all the questions are retrieved regardless of what tags they have or if they have any to begin with(**tags are not mandatory**, although that shouldn't matter).

Do note, I'm not receiving and sort of errors, everything works fine, except for the fact that it retrieves unintended results.

---

**What I've tried so far**

Almost anything I can think of.

The queries run are like so:

```
select * from `users` where `id` = '1' limit 1

select count(*) as aggregate from `questions`

select * from `questions` order by `created_at` desc limit 10 offset 0

select `tags`.*, `tag_question`.`question_id` as `pivot_question_id`, `tag_question`.`tag_id` as `pivot_tag_id` from `tags` inner join `tag_question` on `tags`.`id` = `tag_question`.`tag_id` where `tag_question`.`question_id` in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56') and `tag` = 'test'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`->whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) instead of `with()`:

```
$q = $question
    ->whereHas('tags', function($query) use($request) {
        $query->where('tags.tag', '=',  $request->query('tag'));
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);
```

However, this will not eager load the tags. So you still need to add `->with('tags')`, if you'd like to eager load the tags as well.

Comment: Well that was easier than I expected. Thanks a bunch. I don't really care about eager loading as there aren't going to be that many question->tags to begin with.